# bash script to find a file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a bash script to search for files. If the file is found the script should copy it. Otherwise the script should print a message to notify me that it wasn't found.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
result=/home/images/newfolder/
while read -r $FILE
do
  FOUND="($find $(pwd) -name "$FILE"* -type f print -quit)"
  if [ "x$FOUND" != "x" ]
  then
    echo "copying file: $FOUND"
    cp "$FOUND" $result
  else
    echo "NOT FOUND: $FILE"
  fi
done </root/filelist.txt
```

```
FOUND 11234567890.jpeg
NOT FOUND 1890.jpeg
FOUND 183290.jpeg
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear what your question is. Does your code work, and if not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Your script has a number of problems.  Whenever you have a shell script problem, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: Using "x" in this way: `[ "x$FOUND" != "x" ]` is archaic and from a time when the Bourne shell didn't have proper quoting support. Please don't use it. This would be preferred: `[ "$found" != "" ]` or even better: `[ -n "$found" ]` (Note that I changed your variable to a lower case one. You shouldn't use all-caps variable names in order to avoid potential conflict with shell or environment variables.) Since you're using Bash, you should use double square brackets and the quotes can be omitted: `[[ -n $found ]]`. Always quote your variables when they're used like this: `cp "$found" "$result"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a working script. assuming that you have a `/tmp/filelist.txt` containing what you looking for and files are going to be copied to `/tmp`. fill free to edit and use.

```
#!/bin/bash
result=/tmp
while read -r FILE
do
  FOUND=$(find $(pwd) -name "$FILE" -type f)
  if [ -z "$FOUND" ]; then
    echo "NOT FOUND: $FILE"
  else
    echo "copying file: $FILE"
    cp $FILE $result
  fi
done < /tmp/filelist.txt
```